# Is the VSE multi-threaded?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, performance

So I am thinking of doing an AMD build with the fx-8370 and want to use Blender's video editing component for video editing but I do not know if it will utilize all eight cores.

Should I look to some other video editing software to utilize all eight cores for video editing or will Blender do it?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7750/599

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience with Blender 2.72, even if it is threaded, it is not very good at utilizing more than 2 cores.

I've also done some benchmark on sequencer performance here: [Render times for standard non-3d video](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18794/2217).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pulverize to do multi-process rendering from Blender's Video Sequence Editor:

https://github.com/sciactive/pulverize

Pulverize will render multiple parts of your video in separate processes, then concatenate them into one video file using FFMPEG. It uses the Blender command line to select frame ranges for each render.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on your answer. Link only answers are discouraged here, if the link goes down you answer becomes useless for future visitors. Please edit your question and write something locally about the link, what the addon does or and provide some details about how to use it.